# dplyr - convert column names containing words to character

Tags: r, dplyr, character, names

I want to convert column names that start with the word "feature" to character type using dplyr. I tried the below and a few other variations using answers from stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
train %>% mutate_if(vars(starts_with("feature")), funs(as.character(.)))

train %>% mutate_if(vars(starts_with("feature")), funs(as.character(.)))
```

I am trying to improve my usage of dplyr commands.

Comment: Try `mutate_at` , `train %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("feature")), as.character)`

Comment: And, these days, the `funs()` isn't necessary if you don't need any other arguments. `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("feature")), as.character)` should do just fine. (As explanation, use `mutate_if` when the condition depends on a test about **the data** in the column. `vars()` returns specific columns, and `mutate_at` works on specific columns).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Ronak's answer worked for me.

Comment: Would you mind posting the solution as an answer so that I can mark is Solved?

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to combine multiple arguments for multiple matches? for example, can I combine.   `merchants %<>% mutate_at(vars(contains("_id") )  , as.character)`.  and  
   `merchants %<>% mutate_at(vars(contains("category_") )  , as.character)`. into a single command?

Comment: @user13874 updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `mutate_at` instead

```
library(dplyr)
train %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("feature")), as.character)
```

As @Gregor mentioned, `mutate_if` is when selection of column is based on the actual data in the column and not the names.

For example,

```
iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, sqrt)
```

So if the data in the column is numeric only then it will calculate square root.

If we want to combine multiple `vars` statement into one we can use `matches`

```
merchants %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("_id|category_")), as.character)
```